# Control.Invalidate(region) and Graphics.TranslateTransform ()

Tags: c#

I am working on an analog clock control. Every second I have to update the control to reflect the current time. My timer tick event handler updates the current time.

```
protected virtual void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Time = DateTime.Now;
}
```

with the Time property specified as follows :

```
[Category("ClockData"), Description("Clock time to display."), Browsable(false)]
public DateTime Time
{
    get { return m_Time; }
    set
    {
        m_Time = value;

        Invalidate(GetTimeClipRegion(value));
    }
}
```

The intention is that every second not the entire clock is repainted, but just the clock hands. GetTimeClipRegion() returns the outline of the clock hands in coordinates relative to the center of the control. Therefore in the painthandler I shift the origin (0,0) to the center of the control :

```
private void AnalogClock_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(Size.Width / 2.0f, Size.Height / 2.0f);
    :
}
```

For some reason the TranslateTransform() effects the incoming clipping region.
I think it is because the clipping region set by Invalidate() is assigned before the call to TranslateTransform().

When I comment out TranslateTransform() all seems to work but only a quarter of the clock is drawn which is normal. How can I adapt the incoming clipping region in the paint handler to the new coordinate system ?

Comment: Unless your clock is huge invalidating the whole face will make a big difference. Make sure to double buffer it, though.. Also: Did you invalidate both the old and the new areas of the hands?